# What product should we use to finish stair treads?

Tags: paint, stairs, stain

We are preparing to paint or stain interior basement stairs in a rental house.  What product would be best for finishing the treads?  We need to consider durability, non-slick surface and fast dry/cure time.

Comment: Are you the landlord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~20 years landlord experience, we learned to stop painting all the trim white and use poly. It looks nicer/more expensive and does not *definitely* need attention every time it's up for rent. Paint gets dirty, urethane just looks properly aged.

Whatever it is, if it's made out of *lumber*, stain and urethane it.

Comment: Will urethane make it slippery?  And is solid stain a good choice, given the steps aren't in perfect condition?

Comment: @RET Slippy-er than bare wood, yes. Then paint IDK, unless you use anti-skid. If there's heavy damage you may want to just paint them or urethane without stain. You said 'preparing' I pictured nice pretty bare wood, easy to sand; if there's paint already just paint 'em. Wanting durability over dry time, use oil based.

Comment: @RET:  It was slippery at first but as it wore, it came to have more traction than the bare wood.  This was in a college house for 50 males.  For the first 3-4 coats of urethane, it is fine to sand between to keep it smooth.  But for the last few coats, do *not* sand so it stays a bit rougher.

Comment: They aren't heavily damaged, just some old embedded paint in the 'grooves', and along the nose of the tread. We need to use a solid coverage product so the old paint would be completely covered.  Would oil paint or solid stain be the most durable?

Comment: @RET An appropriate number of coats of urethane (3 or more) would be more durable, but it will be a lot more work. Painted floors might show noticeably in 1~2 years. A wood finish; upwards of 10.

Comment: By wood finish do you mean a stain? In our case it would need to be a solid stain.

Comment: @RET Stain is just the coloring part before the multi-step process of urethaning wood; sand, stain (optional), varnish = wood finish. Unless you're familiar with finishing hardwood floors you prob just want to paint.

Comment: It is not preferable to have the stairs 'tied up' too long with the drying/curing of the multiple layers of urethane.Your advice is good ~ will probably save us from a few 'headaches'.  Thanks!